# How do I select the highest BidAmount for each CarID

Tags: sql

I am trying to select data from a CarDetails table and a BidDetails table that references the `CarID. BidDetails` has multiple "bids" that reference the same car.

```
CarDetails Columns: CarID, Make,...

BidDetails Columns: CarID, BidderID, Amount
```

The selected data is supposed to be the data from the CarDetails table for each car as well as only the highest `bid` that was made for each car.

I however select every bid along with the corresponding car information.

Instead of:

```
CarID: 1 , Make: Toyota, BidAmount: 50000;
CarID: 2 , Make: Honda, BidAmount: 95000
```

I get:

```
CarID: 1 , Make: Toyota, BidAmount: 50000;
CarID: 1 , Make: Toyota, BidAmount: 30000;
CarID: 2 , Make: Honda, BidAmount: 95000
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for simple aggregation ?

```
SELECT CD.CarID, CD.Make, MAX(BD.BidAmount)
FROM CarDetails CD INNER JOIN
     BidDetails BD
     ON BD.CarID = CD.CarID
GROUP BY CD.CarID, CD.Make;
```

If table has more columns which are also you want then you need correlated `subquery` :

```
SELECT CD.CarID, CD.Make, BD.BidAmount
FROM CarDetails CD INNER JOIN
     BidDetails BD
     ON BD.CarID = CD.CarID
WHERE BD.BidAmount = (SELECT MAX(BD1.BidAmount) FROM BidDetails BD1 WHERE BD1.CarID = CD.CarID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
select carid, make,max(bidamount) as bidamount
from CarDetails CD INNER JOIN BidDetails BD
group by carid, make
```